# how to re-fetch the content in MainActivity when returned from another activity?

Tags: android, refresh

I have an activity that send data to server, and after clicked "send" button, **the current activity will finish and return to the main activity**. In the MainActivity, I used an AsyncTask to fetch data from database. **how to re-fetch the content in MainActivity** when the current activity get finished?

I tried to do it as followinng in the MainActivity, but the app won't start correctly, it keeps finish and launch and finish and launch...

```
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    finish();
    startActivity(getIntent());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A potential solution to this is to implement an [AsyncTaskLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html) for your activity, and have the activity implement the [LoaderManager.Callbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.html) interface. The AsyncTaskLoader can listen for a broadcast intent even when your MainActivity has been paused. When you restart MainActivity the loader will deliver the updated content.

The links I have included suggest that this is only available from API 11+ but it is also available in compatibility v4.

For an example implementation of the Loader there is a really good blog series at [Android Design Patterns](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html). I could imagine a situation where your loader has it's own observer to listen out for a broadcast intent once the user hits the send button.